# Failed to dynamically drop table in PL / SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

**What i am trying to do**

I am trying to create a procedure which accepts table_name as its parameter. And inside the procedure i am dynamically dropping the table using [Dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011)

**What is the problem**

After calling the procedure by writing `execute droptab('TEST');` i get the following error:

```
ERROR at line 1:    
ORA-00950: invalid DROP option    
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.DROPTAB", line 4    
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

**Procedure**

```
create or replace procedure dropTab (tableName in varchar2) is

    begin   
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE' || tableName;    
    end;
    /
```

Comment: Try to add the database name before your table name like database.table. And try to execute it in a normal sql window maybe you don't have the rights granted for that.

Comment: `'DROP TABLE' || tableName;` there is no space between `TABLE` and `tablename`, if the tablename is `sometable` the final command is `DROP TABLEsometable` which is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
 'DROP TABLE'
```

to

```
  'DROP TABLE '
```

I.e. add an additional space

Comment: lol that did solved it :) but why do we have to add this space ? thanks.

Comment: So the SQL statement becomes `drop table <table name>` and not `drop table<table name>`